# C# Actions and GC

Tags: c#, delegates, garbage-collection

I am using Actions in C# and I was wondering if I need to set the instance of Action to null once I wish the GC to collect the objects properly? Here is an example:

```
public class A
{
 public Action a;
}

public class B
{
  public string str;
}

public class C
{
 public void DoSomething()
 {
   A aClass = new A();
   B bClass = new B();
   aClass.a = () => { bClass.str = "Hello"; }
 }
}
```

Inside my Main method I have something like this:

```
public void Main(...)
{
  C cClass = new C();
  cClass.DoSomething();

  Console.WriteLine("At this point I dont need object A or B anymore so I would like the GC to collect them automatically.");
  Console.WriteLine("Therefore I am giving GC time by letting my app sleep");
  Thread.Sleep(3000000);
  Console.WriteLine("The app was propably sleeping long enough for GC to have tried collecting objects at least once but I am not sure if A and B objects have really been collected");
 }
}
```

Please read the Console.WriteLine text it will help you understand what I am asking here.

If I apply my understanding of GC to this example the GC would never collect the objects since A cannot be destroyed because it holds instance of B. Am I right?

How can I properly collect those two objects? Do I need to set instances of Actions to null just to let GC collect objects before the end of application or is there already some kind of very smart mechanism by GC that knows how to destroy objects who have Actions such as A and B are?

**EDIT:** The question is about GC and collecting objects properly. Its not about calling the method collect().

Comment: You should be calling `GC.Collect()` followed by `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` to ensure the GC has run. Sleeping for a long time is no guarantee that the GC will run.

Comment: Calling `Thread.Sleep` isn't going to trigger a GC - it only normally runs when it cannot make an allocation in generation 0. You can force it to run with `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: You can call [`GC.Collect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx). I'm dubious that the Sleep will prompt any collection - I believe the CLR waits until you _need_ mem to collect aggressively. Also it won't collect anything that has a reference so you do need to set the variables to null.

Comment: @dlev Not answering the question on closure.

Comment: In debug mode the GC does not collect objects referenced from current method, so ensure that you are running in release mode..

Comment: @Aron I didn't answer *any* part of the question. I merely pointed out that if the OP wants to make sure the GC is run, then he needs to *make sure the GC is run*. Also, the fact that there is a closure isn't actually relevant here.

Comment: Doesnt matter if i call collect() or sleep the question is about how to have nice memory footprints.. how to close objects properly?

Comment: @dlev the question is about the behavior of the GC with reference to how it will deal with a capture, whether it will collect a capture or not.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog as long as `aClass` is in scope it will not collect. As long as `aClass` isn't collected, `bClass` cannot collect.

Comment: Let me edit the question. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: What is `b.str` in your program? There is no local named `b`. Was this intended to be `bClass`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are numerous problems with this question. Rather than answer your question directly I'm going to answer the questions you should be asking.

Let's first disabuse you of your notions about the GC.

> Will sleeping for a long time activate the garbage collector?

No.

> What activates the garbage collector?

For testing purposes you can use `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`. Use these only for testing purposes; it is a bad practice to use them in production code except in some very rare circumstances.

Under normal situations the things that trigger a GC are complicated; the GC is a highly tuned piece of machinery.

> What are the semantics of garbage collection insofar as closed-over outer variables are concerned?

The *lifetime* of a closed-over outer variable of a lambda that is converted to a delegate is *extended* to be *not shorter than the lifetime of the delegate*.

> Suppose I have a variable of type `Action` which is initialized with a lambda that is closed over an outer local variable of reference type. In order to make the object referred to by that variable eligable for collection, do I have to set the variable of type `Action` to `null`?

In the vast majority of cases, no. **The garbage collector is very smart; just let it do its work and do not worry about it**.  Eventually the runtime will determine that the `Action` variable cannot be reached by any live root and will make it eligable for collection; the closed-over outer variable will then become eligible.

There may be extremely rare situations in which you want to throw away references to the `Action` sooner, but they are rare; the vast majority of time, just let the GC do its job without interference.

> Are there situations in which outer variables can have their lifetimes extended too long?

Yes. Consider:

```
void M()
{
    Expensive e = new Expensive();
    Cheap c = new Cheap();
    Q.longLived = ()=>c; // static field
    Q.shortLived = ()=>e; // static field
}
```

When `M()` is executed a closure is created for both delegates. Suppose that `shortLived` is going to be set to `null` soon, and `longLived` is set to `null` far in the future. Unfortunately *both* local variables have their lifetimes extended to the lifetime of the object referred to by `longLived`, even though only `c` is still reachable. The expensive resource `e` is not released until the reference in `longLived` is dead.

Numerous programming languages have this problem; some implementations of JavaScript, Visual Basic, and C# all have this problem. There is some talk of fixing it in the Roslyn release of C# / VB but I do not know if that will come to fruition.

In that case the solution is to avoid the situation in the first place; don't make two lambdas that share a closure if one of the delegates will live much longer than the other.

> Under what circumstances does a local that is *not* a closed-over outer variable become eligable for collection?

The *moment* that the runtime can *prove* that a local cannot be read from again, the thing it references becomes eligable for collection (assuming the local is the only root of course.)  In your example program there is no requirement that the references in `aClass` and `bClass` remain alive until the end of the method. In fact, there are rare but possible circumstances in which the GC can be deallocating an object on one thread *while it is still in its constructor on another thread*! The GC can be *very* aggressive about determining what is dead, so be careful.

> How do I keep something alive in the face of an aggressive GC?

`GC.KeepAlive()` of course.

Answer (score 6):

> I am using Actions in C# and I was wondering if I need to set the instance of Action to null once I wish the GC to collect the objects properly?

Not necessarily.  As long as no object is reachable which references the delegate, the delegate will be eligible for GC.

That being said, in your example, `aClass` and `bClass` are still valid variables, and refer to reachable objects.  This means that `aClass.a` is still reachable, and not eligible for GC, so it will not be collected.

If you wanted these to be garbage collected, you would need to explicitly set the object reference (`aClass`) to null so that the `A` instance, and it's contained delegate, were no longer reachable objects, and then you'd have to explicitly call `GC.Collect` to trigger the GC, since nothing will cause the GC to trigger in your code.

Comment: the GC may collect `aClass`, nothing prevents that.

Comment: @Aron No it can't.  `aClass` is still in scope.

Comment: @Servy Thank you Servy. What I meant to say is that nothing prevents `aClass` from being collected once it goes out of scope. Which also allows `bClass` to be collected.

Comment: @Servy - Objects in scope can still be eligible for collection if they are no longer referenced, although I think the CLR only does this in release mode.

Comment: @Servy I think it actually depends; in a debug build, `aClass` will never be collected. In a release build, I believe the GC may determine that `aClass` is no longer needed and is thus eligible for collection. Scope is a syntactic concept, and the GC doesn't have to honor it if it detects that it doesn't need to.

Comment: Please take a look now at my question.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog `aClass` still goes out of scope at the same times as `bClass`. However if you were returning `aClass` that would be a different story...which is what I suspect you want to know about.

Comment: @Aron the DoSomething() method gets executed and its gone. Still inside aclass there is an Action that holds bcass. So basically even when DoSomething is gone, the objects wont get collected ever. Am i right?

Comment: @snowyhedgehog No. `aClass` isn't referenced anywhere. `bClass` is referenced, but only in `aClass`. So `aClass` is allowed to be collected. `bClass` may only be collected AFTER `aClass`.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog The GC will likely collect all 3 objects (aClass, bClass, and the delegate) at the same time, since it'll see, after the method returns, that none are "reachable" by active code.

Comment: @ReedCopsey even thought objects are out of scope after method calls they still share instances among each other. Does that matter to GC?

Comment: @snowyhedgehog No - you can have interdependencies, and the GC handles it.  It only matters if there is a variable somewhere in scope that, directly or through other variables, makes the object discoverable.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog actually in this case the object graph is completely linear. Its one of the simplest cases for the GC to handle. The fun starts with cyclic dependencies (which all GCs SHOULD deal with).

Comment: The level of misinformation in these comments is extremely high. @snowyhedgehog: You should only believe about half of what you read in these comments, because that's about how much is correct.

Comment: @Aron you are throwing around with some cyclic dependecies things that I dont get. hehe. Can you use plain english please.

Comment: @EricLippert I am confused now.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog Don't worry. Just consider the GC to be magic.

Comment: @Aron thats what i Dont want to consider.

Comment: @Aron: Re: `bClass` may only be collected after `aClass` is completely false.

Comment: @EricLippert Okay. Assuming that `aClass.b` is not set after it is constructed...Way too used to immutables...

Comment: @Aron Even if you leave this as is, it's still false.  If `aClass` references `bClass`, they can still be collected in the same GC pass.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog Okay. GC may only collect objects that are unreachable. However unreachable by the programmer does not always mean unreachable by the GC (consider private variables).

Comment: @snowyhedgehog: Let's consider the program you posted. Is the GC permitted to deallocate any of those objects in any order?  **Yes**.  Why?  **Because the program provably does nothing.**  The jitter is permitted to codegen your program as *an empty Main*, and elide *all* of the allocations. Or it can generate some of the allocations and not others. It can do anything it likes, so long as the result is a program which terminates after doing nothing. **The jitter is permitted to make any optimization which does not change the observed output**.

Comment: @ReedCopsey sematics. The same pass, but the GC needs to mark `aClass` first.

Comment: So all of these suppositions about what *must* happen in what order in your program are false suppositions. We can discuss what *does* happen *in a particular implementation*, but that's an implementation detail, not a requirement.

Comment: @Aron No, it doesn't.  The GC doesn't go around marking objects to collect.  It goes around marking objects to *keep*.  It then keeps all of the objects that it knows it needs to keep and discards all of the objects it knows it doesn't need *all a the same time*.

Comment: @Aron: The GC is not required to mark anything in any order. The GC has complete lattitude to do whatever the heck it wants in whatever order it wants. Moreover I think you are misunderstanding how a mark-and-sweep collector works.

Comment: sigh...okay...I am going to concede if only because I don't want to go into an arguement into GC design. Or what is a good model of how to think about how the GC is working for the purpose of prevention of memory leaks.

Comment: @EricLippert That is an extremely good point, too.  The language specs provide very little requirements to garbage collection, and nothing in terms of required implementation details (from what I recall) other than the GC has a lot of latitude in how and when things occurs other than when it "is impossible for any user-written code to access" the objects.

Comment: Dont start fighting hehe. How about you all agree who is most right and he may post an solution plus edit my question in such way that others understand it in case there is somebody looking for how gc collects actions in future?

Comment: @snowyhedgehog If you can be bothered to read and understand all of Eric's answer it is perhaps the best answer you will get here.

Comment: English is my second language. Eric posted alot and i am still trying to decrypt that hehe. I thought I would post a question about how gc collects such actions. Or generally how does GC collect things. I think It would be nice if me and others could find some nice simple plain easy explaination here.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog: If you want to ask the specific question "do I need to set the action variable to null in order to avoid a memory leak?" the answer is 99% of the time: *no*; just relax and let the GC do its job. If you want to ask the general question "how does the .NET garbage collector work?" I suggest you read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx and then come back when you have more questions.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog Also note that "how does the .NET garbage collector work" is way too broad of a question for SO.  Books can and have literally be written on the subject.

Comment: And of course above I meant to say that Main could be optimized away to be empty *except for the Console.WriteLines* of course. The jitter can know that calling `DoSomething` in fact does *nothing visible* and optimize it all away if it chooses.

Comment: Ok one more question. Inside my aClass I am holding reference to bClass. How does GC collect aclass and bclass since aclass needs bclass and bclass cannot be collected since aclass needs it?

Comment: @snowyhedgehog The GC sees that nothing "outside" of aClass or bClass needs those two objects, and collects both.  Basically, it walks the objects, and sees that no code references either object (from anything used in your actual code), and collects both, even though they refer to each other.

Comment: @snowyhedgehog: In 30 seconds, the GC works like this: imagine you have a whiteboard full of red boxes with arrows between them. Choose some boxes as "living" and color them green. Now, every red box that is pointed to by a green box, color it green too. Keep doing that until there are no more red boxes pointed to by a green box. Now *erase all the red boxes from the whiteboard*, and re-colour all the green boxes red. That's how the garbage collector works. When the jitter knows that `aClass` is never read from again, it stops coloring it green; it stays red, and disappears.